# Pass multiple numbers from keyboard via vim normal mode as arguments of function

Tags: vim

e.g. In normal mode I type

```
123 456<Enter>
```

I would like to pass numbers `123` and `456` to be arguments of vim function.

Code example:

```
function! PrintNum(A, B)
    echo A B
endfunction

nmap A B<Enter> call PrintNum(A, B)
```

where `A` and `B` could be any numbers with `space` delimiter. Note that function `PrintNum()` is just used for testing that two numbers are passed through the function correctly.

Comment: What's the actual use case? You certainly don't want to print those numbers, right? Are those dimensions, phone numbers, and why does it have to be a mapping? Will you be invoking this very often (and with different numbers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### direct answer

Here's what you're asking for, with the caveat that this is highly ususual:

```
function! PrintNum(b)
    echo g:a a:b
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Space> :<C-u>let g:a = v:count<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Enter> :<C-u>call PrintNum(v:count)<CR>
```

#### canonical Vim style

Mappings usually only take a *count* and/or a *register*. If you need more, usually a custom *command* is used:

```
command! -nargs=+ PrintNum call PrintNum(<f-args>)
```

If that is too much to type, you can define a trigger mapping, so you only need to enter the numbers and acknowledge with <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
nnoremap <Enter> :PrintNum<Space>
```

#### alternative

Or, the mapping could query for the parameters:

```
nnoremap <Enter> :call PrintNum(input('First number: '), input('Second number: '))<CR>
```